# Deployed Web ACS Service cannot access camera from Safari on iPhone

Tags: azure-communication-services

We are working on building a web application using ACS that would be accessed through the desktop as well as mobile devices. We've found a way to render the local and remote video on the screen from the desktop computers, unfortunately, there is no video stream being transmitted when using the website calling through the iPhone. Not sure if this might be the camera device selection problem, in all instances we use

```
const videoDeviceInfo = cameras[0];
```

We then proceed to pass in the `videoDeviceInfo` into the call that is initiated. Any ideas on what might be missing on safari that's working on the desktop would be highly appreciated!